# WP-ecommerce ajax error wpsc_ajax not defined

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I’ve got a problem with my WP-ecommerce plugin (3.8.12.1) in wordpress. My add to cart button refreshes the page. I’m getting an javascript error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: wpsc_ajax is not defined in wp-e-commerce.js on line 275:

```
jQuery.post( wpsc_ajax.ajaxurl, form_values, success, 'json' );
```

This means my jquery.post is not performed and a normal post action is performed. I am not sure when this problem started to occur but I think it was when I installed w3 total cache (a wordpress cache plugin). Does anybody know where wpsc_ajax is defined or what the actual problem might be? Any help in the right direction is appreciated, I'm kind of stuck!

Cheers,
Adnan

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just replacing the ajax url with the path to the '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' worked out fine

Comment: You should [read this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13277/wp-ajax-question-not-using-wp-enqueue-script) to understand `ajaxurl`.

Comment: I see, so it's probably because I am hardcoding the wp-ecommerce js from the header in stead of enqueing it. Thanks!